# Displaying decreasing minutes and seconds on 5 labels in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am making an app in Swift which has a countdown timer that has to display minutes and seconds on 5 labels, to be exact, this is the formation:

[9][9][9] : [5][9]

// 999:59

So, in a principle which old odometers in cars used to count mileage, or one of those old flipping number clocks.

I will be using labels just as a testing model, later they will be replaced by image sets but I need the logic for the number display.

I managed to make a simple countdown using `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0...)` and a separate function where I subtract one number from the total number which is written or declared. i.e.

```
var initialTime:Int = 60   
var timerSeconds = NSTimer()

func timerTick() {
    timerSeconds = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "startCount", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} 

func startCount() {
    initialTime--
}
```

And displaying the total time is no issue, but to separate the total time into minutes and seconds, AND to separate those two into 3 labels for minutes and 2 for seconds...I've been trying for hours and I can't think of anything. I am relatively new to swift so pardon if I missed out something. Thanks!

Comment: multiple timers can use the same countdown/countup method. And you don't need a timer just for seconds and one for minutes, you can just use one timer method and and separate it in to sections `minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60` `seconds = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60`

Comment: Hover your mouse over the xcode tag you used and read when that tag is appropriate. Considering your question has nothing (even remotely) to do with xcode, please edit your question to remove that tag. Invalid use of tags is distracting to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specific to Swift. Using the timer correctly is a Foundation classes question.

Calculating the different digits is basic computer math.

Don't decrement a counter each time your timer fires. Timers sometimes "miss" (fail to get called) if your app gets busy.

Instead, record the `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() + secondsToCompletion` when you start the timer.

```
let finishedInterval = 
  NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() + secondsToCompletion
```

Then each time the timer fires, calculate the new remaining seconds and use that for your math:

```
let remainingSeconds = Int(round(finishedInterval -
  NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()))
//Then do math on the time to get your digits:

let secondsOnesPlace = remainingSeconds % 10
let secondsTensPlace = (remainingSeconds % 60) / 10

let remainingMinutes  = remainingSeconds / 60


let remainingMinutesOncePlace = remainingMinutes % 10
let remainingMinutesTensPlace = (remainingMinutes / 10) % 10
let remainingMinutesHundredsPlace = (remainingMinutes / 100) % 10

println("\(remainingMinutesHundredsPlace)\(remainingMinutesTensPlace)\(remainingMinutesOncePlace):\(secondsTensPlace)\(secondsOnesPlace)")
```

Then use all the "...place" values to set your label digits/images.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Duncan, will try out your method and let you know how it works. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Umm...I tried your method, some parts did work exactly as I wanted them, but others not quite. So, the issue here is that I don't get minutes and hours correct. The output looks like this:  The first digit for the Seconds counter counts from 6-0 and the second digit counts from 9-0, which is good. But the Hours Digit and minutes digit does the exact same thing, my pardon on lack of basic knowledge here, like I said, I am very new to swift and I know this is a simple issue but my head hurts right now.

Comment: There were multiple mistakes in my code. I actually wrote a test program and debugged it. The edited code should now work.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait to reply, had like a ton of work on my hands. Anyways, works great, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timer I would recommend to use `CADisplayLink` with 1fps, would be MUCH better than any timers.

Parsing time to 5 labels (skipping dot):

```
let time = 87.6543

let timeString = String(format: "%06.2f", time % 1000)
// 087.65

for (index, char) in enumerate(timeString) {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        let label1 = char
    case 1:
        let label2 = char
    case 2:
        let label3 = char
    case 4:
        let label4 = char
    case 5:
        let label5 = char
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but will work.

Comment: Using CADisplayLink seems like overkill for a timer that fires once/second. The inaccuracy of NSTimer is on the order of 1/50th of a second, which is fine for a whole second countdown timer.

Comment: I tested it, and a 1-second CADisplayLink timer drifts if it's run on the main run loop while time-consuming code is also running (In the test case, an NSTimer that fires ~every .07 seconds and does a  loop counting to 10,000,000).

Comment: By comparison, a 1-second NSTimer's fire time might be delayed, but it doesn't drift further and further from the desired interval. The fire time is sometimes "spot-on", and other times a fraction of a second late, but doesn't drift. So a display link timer isn't always the better solution.

Comment: @DuncanC thank you for your research, will keep it in mind for the future.